# Set Datatable name to collection - C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to assign datatable in collection/array as below

```
object[] dtObj = {Datatable1,Datatable2};
```

and loop like this,

```
for(int i=0; i<dtObj.lengt; i++)
{
 foreach(Datarow row in dtObj[i].Rows)
 {
   // logic here
 }
}
```

This way I want to loop through the datable one by one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by **not** declaring it as `object[]` but as `DataTable[]`. If it has to be an `object[]` for whatever reason, you have to cast it to `DataTable` in the loop:

```
foreach(Datarow row in ((DataTable)dtObj[i]).Rows)
{
   // logic here
}
```

If you want to add other objects than `DataTable` to this `object[]`, you can use `OfType`:

```
foreach(DataTable table in dtObj.OfType<DataTable>())
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. As advised creating Datatable[] satisfied my purpose.